# Remove space between rows of table in latex

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to change the color of rows in a longtable latex. The problem is that, I have merged some rows but when I change the background color of cells there is a space between merged rows which is white. You can see it in screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of output]

```
\begin{scriptsize}

\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}



\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}




\caption{Clustering Techniques}
\label{clusteringtechs}

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\#} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Clustering\\ Technique\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Year} & \rotatebox{90}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Support\\Heterogeneity\end{tabular}}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Role\\ of\\ CH\end{tabular}}&\rotatebox{90}{\centering \multirow{2}{*}{Routing}} &
\rotatebox{90}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}support\\Mobility\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{17}{c|}{Objectives} \\ \cline{5-6} \cline{9-25} 
 &  &  &  & \rotatebox{90}{Relay} & \rotatebox{90}{Fusion} &  &  & E & L & R & D & J & T & Y & P & C & O & F & B & A & M & S & U & H \\ \hline
 \endhead
 \toprule
% &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Role\\ of\\ CH\end{tabular}} &  &  & \multicolumn{17}{c|}{Objectives} \\ \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){9-25} 
%\multirow{-2}{*}{\#} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Clustering\\ Technique\end{tabular}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Year} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Support\\ Heter\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Relay} & Fusion & \multirow{-2}{*}{Routing} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}support \\ Mobility\end{tabular}} & E & L & R & D & J & T & Y & P & C & O & F & B & A & M & S & U & H \\ \midrule
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code.

Comment: Your code still is not compilable. Please include the document class, the required packages, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as well. And your table code is incomplete as well.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to compile your code by adding a document preamble, but it is to many error in the code.

You are using the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)-package and `toprule` `midrule` etc. Neither `rowcolor` nor `cellcolor` will colourise the extra space `booktabs` provides above and below of the rules. Also, it is documented in the manual that `toprule` and friends are not compatible with vertical lines.

You can try `hline` and `cline` and load the [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package. However, you will then see that some of the rules seem to disappear in the PDF-viewer.

I suggest that you build the table using only horizontal line, as recommended in the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual. Also, remove the `rowcolor` which is unnecessary. In addition, add `@{}`ad the beginning and end of the table preamble, to remove the side bearings.

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}*{25}{l}@{}}  % 25 left aligned columns
```

If you need a multi page tabular environment that handles colourised cells and horizontal and vertical rules, a possible solution is to use the [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)-package.

Here is the calstable version:

```
\documentclass[british, DIV=12, captions=tableheading, landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, url}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor, lscape}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\addtokomafont{caption}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{calstable}[c]

\captionaboveof{table}{Clustering Techniques}
\label{clusteringtechs}

% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26*2+4pt\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/26\relax}
    }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 6

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3.2pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3.2pt}

\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{blue!5}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\sffamily\scriptsize%           The first 5 rows are heading and vill be repeated on every page
\brow
    \alignC\blue\nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R2H2
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil 145}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil DFCR[139]}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil 2015}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil No}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil }
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil X}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil M}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil No}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Fault Tolerance (CH failure)}\blue
\erow
%R3H3
\brow
   \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{\vfil X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R4H4
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil 146}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil K-SCC[140]}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil 2015}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil No}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil }
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil X}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil M}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil No}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Improve security by providing authentication}
\erow
%R5H5
\brow
    \blue\cell{147}
    \cell{DECAR[141]}
    \cell{2015}
    \cell{No}
    \cell{}
    \cell{X}
    \cell{M}
    \cell{No}
    \cell{X}
    \cell{X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{X}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\blue
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R6B1
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow

\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
%\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]